# How to distinct based on previous records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, distinct

Given this structure:

```
+--------+-------+--+
|  Task  |  Job  |  |
+--------+-------+--+
| TASK01 | JOB01 |  |
| TASK02 | JOB01 |  |
| TASK03 | JOB01 |  |
| TASK01 | JOB02 |  |
| TASK02 | JOB02 |  |
| TASK03 | JOB02 |  |
+--------+-------+--+
```

How can I obtain a list of all jobs and one task for each job, the tricky part the task cant repeat between jobs in the resultset i.e:

```
+--------+-------+
| TASK01 | JOB01 |
+--------+-------+
| TASK02 | JOB02 |
+--------+-------+
```

For JOB01 i can get TASK01

For JOB02 i can get TASK02 or TASK03 (but not TASK01 because it is already listed with JOB01 in this result set)
And so on..

Im on SQL server 2000 so i cant use ROW_NUMBER

Comment: What means _previous_ at all? What is the column you want to order by?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I need to get a depurated list, for any given job i need to get one task.. just one task.. but i cant reapeat a task between jobs

Comment: There is no simple SQL solution for this, because there might not be a viable answer.